# transition.retry() seems to be removing the ‘?’ from the query-string

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using the `willTransitionTo` static method for auth.  [Here’s the example](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js) I’m somewhat following.

My `transition.retry()` is going to the original route along with it’s original query-string.  However the query-string is missing the question mark at the beginning, so instead of going to the route that was intended in the transition, it’s going to `/authToken=xyz123`

So,

- the user goes to http://wickedsweet-react-site.com/?authToken=xyz123
- react routes (via `transition.redirect`) to http://wickedsweet-react-site.com/waitforserverauth
- server is authing and returns
- react routes (via `transition.retry()`) to http://wickedsweet-react-site.com/authToken=xyz123 ***oops***

How can I avoid the stripping of the `?`?  Incidentally, I don’t even want the authToken query string at this point because we've already authed, but for now, that’s a secondary concern.

Here is my `willTransitionTo` method.

```
mixins: [Reflux.connect(stores.AuthDataStore, 'auth_data')],
statics: {
    willTransitionTo: function (transition, params, query) {
        var auth_data = stores.AuthDataStore.getData();
        if (!auth_data.authenticated) {
             some_global_object.authTransition = transition;
             if (query.authToken && !_.isEmpty(query.authToken)) {
                 auth.authenticate({token: query.authToken}); // tells server to auth
                 transition.redirect("/waitforserverauth", params, {});  //don’t want the query-string after this point
                 return;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

For authentication I am passing a token into a query-string parameter called ‘authToken’.  When a user passes in the authToken then I am using `willTransitionTo` to ask the server to authenticate and redirect the user to a WaitingForAuth page that listens for the server’s auth.  Here’s the WaitingForAuth React page.

```
var WaitingForServerAuth = React.createClass({
    mixins: [Reflux.connect(stores.AuthDataStore, 'auth_data')],

    componentWillUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
        if (nextState.auth_data.authenticated && some_global_object.authTransition) {
            some_global_object.authTransition.retry();
        }
    },

    render: function() {
        return (<div><Loading /></div>);
    }
});
```

When the server returns with auth and the token is valid, WaitingForAuth implements `componentWillUpdate` which will then retry the original transition that was aborted with the redirect.